# how to change the values in the array list

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I am doing an Assignment in school, where i have to make Restaurant table management system. i have written the following code but i am having problem with the edit items. i am supposed to edit the items in the array list. but i have to make sure when i re-run my program the changes are still there. editMenu() is in Manager class and the array List is in Meal class

Answer (score 2):

> but i have to make sure when i re-run my program the changes are still
>   there.

Use file or database. What you do will vanish when you rerun your program since they are just in the memory before.

Comment: I tried using file processing but my lecturer wants me to do it without the use of any file processing –

Answer (score 1):

When you *re-run the program*, everything starts from zero. You need to *persist* your list in a file or database and read it when you restart your program.

Comment: I tried using file processing but my lecturer wants me to do it without the use of any file processing

Comment: Tell him Stack Overflow disagrees :) He should resign.

Comment: so there is no possible way of doing so?

Comment: @Salman Hanif Really it can be done without using a file or saving them as object? ;( Either the lecturer is drunk or i don't even know ... Give me the light...and the phone of the teacher..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preferences to store information.like key value pair..